# Bootstrap: Keeping the input fields inline in a fluid span

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, styling, css

How can I keep input fields inline in each fluid span?

```
            <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
                <div class="span6"><label>First Name:</label><input type="text"/></div>
                <div class="span6">span6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
                <div class="span6">span6</div>
                <div class="span6">span6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
                <div class="span6">span6</div>
                <div class="span6">span6</div>
            </div>
```

I am going to dynamically generate each row. Tried changing `display:` to inline or `inline-block` in `show-grid` class but it didn't work.

```
.show-grid [class*="span"] {
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: try to change the label to inline or inline-block, probably that causes problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the class `form-inline` in each `span6`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TTVG8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
    <div class="span6 form-inline">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="span6">span6</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
    <div class="span6">span6</div>
    <div class="span6">span6</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
    <div class="span6">span6</div>
    <div class="span6">span6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
.show-grid[class*="span"] {
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kamil is right. Change to `display:inline`, or as a last resource `float:left;`

Comment: Do you mean changing it for label?